# Android Spinner: Cannot selected

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have the code, which unfortunately does not work as it should. More specifically, we can not choose from the second spinner. Here is the code. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
public class Zamiana extends Activity {
public Spinner spinner1;
public Spinner spinner2;
final ArrayList<Spanned> kon = new ArrayList<Spanned>();


[...]

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.test);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.test2);


    ArrayList<Spanned> adapter = new ArrayList<Spanned>();
    adapter.add(Html.fromHtml("t0"));
    adapter.add(Html.fromHtml("t1"));
    adapter.add(Html.fromHtml("t2"));

[...]
ArrayAdapter<Spanned> kontrol = new ArrayAdapter<Spanned>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, adapter);


kontrol.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner1.setAdapter(kontrol);


    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(wyznacz);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(wyznacz);

    ArrayAdapter<Spanned> kontrola = new ArrayAdapter<Spanned>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, kon);


    kontrola.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(kontrola);

}
public OnItemSelectedListener wyznacz=new OnItemSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg2){
        case 0:             
            kon.clear();

            kon.add(Html.fromHtml("t0"));

            break;
        case 1:
            kon.clear();
            kon.add(Html.fromHtml("t1"));
            break;
        case 2:
            kon.clear();
            kon.add(Html.fromHtml("t2"));
            break;
[...]

}

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

Thanks you very much for all help :)

Answer (score 0):

For the spinners I have created I have only used three methods that I would override (onCreate, onItemSelected, onNothingSelected). I am confused why you have an OnItemSelected Listener above your onItemSelected Method since the onItemSelected Method is called when an item is selected.

It's not the best answer and more detail of what your spinner is suppose to achieve would be great but having the onItemSelected Method within an OnItemSelected Event Listener just seems to kind of stand out above everything else.

Hope this helps or points you in the right direction. Good Luck! plus post more code and details about your spinner.